# Php - explode a string with two delimiters

Tags: php, explode

```
$string = 'folder1:image1.jpg|folder2:image2.jpg|folder3:image3.jpg';
```

I need to explode the string to get the following result:

```
<img src="/folder1/image1.jpg" />
<img src="/folder2/image2.jpg" />
<img src="/folder3/image3.jpg" />
```

It's not a problem with one delimiter but I have two delimiters and don't know how to do it:

```
$imagedata = explode("|", $string);
foreach($imagedata as $image) {
echo "$image<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
$string = 'folder1:image1.jpg|folder2:image2.jpg|folder3:image3.jpg';
$imagedata = explode("|", $string);
foreach($imagedata as $image) {
    $img=explode(":", $image);
    echo '<img src="' . $img[0] . '/' . $img[1] . '" /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need two delimiters, you can just do a `str_replace` after you `explode`:

```
$imagedata = explode("|", $string);
foreach($imagedata as $image) {
    echo "<img src='/".str_replace(":","/",$image) . "'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with 2 foreach...

```
$string = 'folder1:image1.jpg|folder2:image2.jpg|folder3:image3.jpg';

$imagedata = explode("|", $string);
foreach($imagedata as $folder) {
    $imageFolders = explode(":", $folder);
    foreach ($imageFolders as $image) {
        echo "$image<br />";
    }
}
```

Then maybe just need to save it on other variable...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it short (but not clear):

```
 $imagedata = '<img src="/' . implode("\" />\n<img src=\"", str_replace(':', '/', explode("|", $string))) . '" />';
```